# Static pages Gatsby in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Established Gatsby Starter
I understand that it should generate static pages
But I open the source code in the browser and see only styles and javascript
What not so?

Comment: Andrei, you’ll need to be more specific. What steps have you taken, what pages have you created and how, what specifically are you seeing compared to what you expect, etc.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation at all? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ - they have all the steps you need to get started with `Gatsby`.

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby only generates static entry pages when you run `gatsby build`. In development mode it avoids this step and simply serves up your pages and components like a client-side rendered React app. This makes it possible to develop quickly with hot–module reloading, author GraphQL queries without restarting the development server, and more.

Comment: I'm running the ```gatsby build``` on Netlify and still see the same issue - https://worksetup.xyz/

Comment: When the page loads, it is empty. A request is made to the backend to fetch the data and then populate the page as you can see here - https://cln.sh/CzBtUi

Comment: @AshitVora Ask a question instead of commenting on an unrelated answer.